# How to Handle Negative Estimates when Using Lindley Approximation Method in Bayesian Estimation

Tags: bayesian, estimation

I am currently working on Bayesian estimation using the Lindley approximation method. However, I have encountered an issue where the estimated results occasionally contain negative values.

I would like to seek guidance on how to handle negative estimates obtained through the Lindley approximation.
Additionally, if there are any alternative approximation methods or modifications to the Lindley approximation that can help address the issue of negative estimates, I would appreciate any insights or recommendations.

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

```
#bayesian

A_rho<-function(params,hyperparams){
  alpha_n<-params[1]
  a<-hyperparams[1]
  b<-hyperparams[2]
  return((a-1)/alpha_n-b)
}
L_rho<-function(params,hyperparams){
  lambda_n<-params[2]
  a<-hyperparams[1]
  b<-hyperparams[2]
  return((a-1)/lambda_n-b)
}

#

Alpha_B<-function(params,cendata,V,hyperparams1,hyperparams2,c){
  alpha_n<-params[1]
  a_rho<-A_rho(params,hyperparams1)
  l_rho<-L_rho(params,hyperparams2)
  t11<-V[1,1]
  t12<-V[1,2]
  t22<-V[2,2]
  
  l30<-l_30(params,cendata)
  l21<-l_21(params,cendata)
  l12<-l_12(params,cendata)
  l03<-l_03(params,cendata)
  
  alpha_S<-alpha_n+1/2*(2*a_rho*t11+2*l_rho*t12+l30*t11^2+3*t11*t12*l21+
                          (2*t12^2+t11*t22)*l12+t12*t22*l03)
  
  alpha_L<-alpha_n-1/c*log(1+c*(1/2*c*t11-(alpha_S-alpha_n)))
  
  output<-list(S=alpha_S,L=alpha_L)
  return(output)
}

Lambda_B<-function(params,cendata,V,hyperparams1,hyperparams2,c){
  lambda_n<-params[2]
  a_rho<-A_rho(params,hyperparams1)
  l_rho<-L_rho(params,hyperparams2)
  t11<-V[1,1]
  t12<-V[1,2]
  t22<-V[2,2]
  l30<-l_30(params,cendata)
  l21<-l_21(params,cendata)
  l12<-l_12(params,cendata)
  l03<-l_03(params,cendata)
  
  lambda_S<-lambda_n+1/2*(2*l_rho*t22+2*a_rho*t12+l03*t22^2+3*t22*t12*l12+
                            (2*t12^2+t11*t22)*l21+t12*t11*l30)
  lambda_L<-lambda_n-1/c*log(1+c*(1/2*c*t22-(lambda_S-lambda_n)))
  output<-list(S=lambda_S,L=lambda_L)
  return(output)
}
```